# how connect to ldap with ldap_sasl_bind in php

Tags: php, ldap, openldap

I have on LDAP this user: uid=user,ou=People,dc=ex,dc=com
I connect to LDAP server with

```
$con = ldap_connect('ldap://ex.com');
ldap_set_option($con, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($con, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
```

I try bind with ldap_sasl_bind:

```
ldap_sasl_bind($con, 'uid=user,ou=People,dc=ex,dc=com', 'secret', 'DIGEST-MD5');
```

not work - "Invalid credentials"

```
ldap_sasl_bind($con, NULL, 'secret', 'DIGEST-MD5', NULL, 'uid=user,ou=People,dc=ex,dc=com');
```

same result - "Invalid credentials"

```
ldap_bind($con, 'uid=user,ou=People,dc=ex,dc=com', 'secret')
```

work fine

Comment: Can you authenticate using a known good tool `ldapsearch` with the same parameters as in the PHP LDAP client?

Comment: Invalid credentials (49) additional info: SASL(-17): One time use of a plaintext password will enable requested mechanism for user: no secret in database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a low-security [SASL](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4422) method like [DIGEST-MD5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2831), the server must be able to get the clear-text password from the entry named by the distinguished name. This means the password must be stored in clear text or with a reversible encryption (this reduces the security if the entry, one reason DIGEST-MD5 should considered low-security and avoided unless required by the LDAP client; LDAP clients should prefer simple authentication using a secure connection).

Check to be sure the entry for `uid=user,ou=People,dc=ex,dc=com` has the password `secret` available to the server, that is, the password storage scheme is either clear-text or a reversible encryption as noted above. If a reversible encryption is used, the strongest method should be used, which I believe is [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES).